# Concrete Model reading xlsx document Pyomo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyomo

I am currently working on a Concrete Model, however, due to the parameters size, it seems very dificult to write almost 200 parameters with this form:

```
model.time = Param(model.WORKS, model.MODELS, initialize={(1,1):2, (2,1):1, (3,1):4, (4,1):2, (5,1):3, (6,1):3, (7,1):1, (8,1):2, (1,2):1, (2,2):2, (3,2):1, (4,2):3, (5,2):3, (6,2):2, (7,2):1, (8,2):1.....})
```

And this this is just one of the parameters.
I would like to read tables from a xls document, something like this:

```
data.load(filename="excel.xlsx", range="Btable", format='set', set='B')
```

It is very difficult to tranform the model into an Abstract model due to the quantities of dictionary and concrete formulas.

Some idea how to do it, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely something that you are able to do. Bill Hart is more familiar with the Pyomo-provided `DataPortal` interface than I am.

I would personally import the Excel data using `pandas` and then write a function (rule) to create the `Param` using the `pandas` `DataFrame` object `xls_data`:

```
xls_data = pandas.read_excel(**see pandas documentation**)

print(xls_data)  # This can help with debugging

@model.Param(model.WORKS, model.MODELS)
def time(m, wrks, mods):
    return float(xls_data[**appropriate index from pandas**])
```